# How to make OpenCV IplImage for 16 bit gray-data?

Tags: opencv, iplimage

This code is for 8 bit data to make gray-scale IplImage.

```
    IplImage* img_gray_resize = NULL;
    img_gray_resize = cvCreateImage(cvSize(320, 256), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    DWORD   dwCount;
    LVDS_SetDataMode(0); // o for 8 bit mode and 1 for 16 bit mode
    dwCount = (LONG)320 * (LONG)256;
    unsigned char* m_pImage = NULL;
    m_pImage = new unsigned char[320 * 256]; 
    for (int i=0; i<320 * 256; i++) m_pImage[i] = NULL;
    LVDS_GetFrame(&dwCount, m_pImage);
    int width = 320;
    int height = 256;
    int nn = 0;
    int ii = 0;
    for (int y=0; y<height; y++) 
    {
        for (int x=0; x<width; x++)  
        {
            ii = y * width + x;
            if(nn < (height*width))
                img_gray_resize->imageData[ii] = m_pImage[nn++];
        }
    }
    delete [] m_pImage;
```

I need to display 16 bit gray-scale image. If I display 8 bit data, some information is missing from the image. However, LVDS_SetDataMode() can provide both types of data. I am using a library for frame grabber device. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

16 bit images should be stored in `IPL_DEPTH_16U` (or `CV_16U`) mode. This is the correct memory layout.

However, *displaying* them depends on your display hardware.
Most regular display APIs, e.g. OpenCV's highgui, can only display 8-bit images.
To actually display the image, you will have to convert your image to 8-bits for display.

You will need to decide how to do this. There are many ways to do this, depending on your application and complexity. Some options are:

- Show MSB = right-shift the image by 8 pixels.
- Show LSB = saturate anything above `255`.
- In fact, right-shift by any value between 0-8 bits, combined with a [cv::saturate_cast](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html#saturate-cast) to avoid value wrap-around.
- HDR->LDR = Apply dynamic range compression algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

as I know,only 8bit data can be displayed,you need to find the best way to convert the 16bit to 8bit to minimize the information you lose. Histogram equalization can be applyed to do this.

Comment: How can i convert 16 bit data to 8 bit data? Please give me some information.

Comment: 1. compute hisgram respect to the 16bit image 2. normlize it to prob and convert to cdf 3. map the index with value cdf to 256 * cdf

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have solved the problem by following way:

```
 dwCount = (LONG)320 * (LONG)256 * 2;
 LVDS_SetDataMode(1);
 img_gray_resize->imageData[ii] = m_pImage[nn++] >> 6;
```

Just shift bits to right (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...), where you get good result, use that value.

Comment: Yes, shifting anywhere between 0-8 bits will show a different band of intensities. However, you must make sure that you actually *saturate* your 8-bit values, otherwise your intensity value will wrap around mod(1<<8). See my answer.